# How to handle line-breaks in HTML forms?

Tags: python, html, forms, post, mechanize

I have a `form` with a `textarea` and need to submit multiple lines of input to the `textarea`.

I use :

```
rows = [('a','b'), ('c','d')]
data_set = [ '%s\n' % '|'.join(row) for row in rows ]  # Note : ADDED '\n'
data_dump = ''.join(data_set)

from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.open('http://example.com/page.html')
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['my_text_area']=data_dump
br.submit()
```

Problem:

- Webserver is not able to see the input as multiple lines.
- ADDED `\n` is not working for simulating line breaks in the inputs.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Feel free to ask for more info if I have missed something !

**Update**

I also tried `\n\r` in place of `\n`, but the problem persists.

Comment: I don't know, since its a public website. I suppose some 'Linux' server. Although, I understand the platform specific line-breaks, but doesn't HTTP protocol covers this thing ? (For this case !)

Comment: That is not part of my code, `data_dump` is just a string with `\n` in it.

Comment: How do you know _webserver is not able to see the input as multiple lines_? Did you look at the raw posted data? Did you just looked at the HTML output from webserver?

Comment: @SalmanA After submitting the data to server, it replies back. When I open that html reply in chrome or firefox, it shows the error `only single line input`. Moreover the data in the reply is present in multiple lines. If I `ctrl-A` then `ctrl-V` and manually submit it to the webpage, it accepts it. But its not accepting it via my script.

Seems like an issue with how chrome and myscript is handling the newlines. 

Also, since mechanize automatically url-encode the data so I don't have the flexibility to make out the raw form for the newline.

Comment: On debugging the `submitted data`, the server is accepting newline as `%0A%0D` where as `\n` is getting converted to `%0A` only.

You can try it on : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: It could be that that the server-side script is expecting a specific line ending. Test with the three common line endings: `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` (not `\n\r`).

Comment: Sure, I will try all the combinations and get back.

Comment: But, how can chrome guess the right mix on the first hit, I think its not about guessing!

Comment: That worked.. and I figured out the reason. I have mentioned that in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a

`CR` = \r
`LF` = \n

And HTML forms take a line-break as `CRLF`, so therefore :

`\r\n` worked !