# Fill web form with text from txt file using Python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to fill a web form with Python mechanize using the text from a txt file, however when the form is filled all return characters / line breaks are lost. Is there a way to get around this? When printing to the console it includes the returns so I'm a little stumped.

```
def load_message():
the_message = open('ra_message.txt', 'r')
message = the_message.read()
the_message.close()
return message

def message(to_user, subject, the_message):
try:
    br.open(ra_message)
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br['addrecipient'] = to_user
    br['subject'] = subject
    br['message'] = the_message
    br.submit()
    print('{} succesfully messaged.'.format(to_user))        
    save_line = to_user + ', TRUE\n'
    save_file = open('messaged_users.csv', 'a')
    save_file.write(save_line)
    save_file.close()
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)

def main():
try:
    the_message = load_message()
    login(username, password)
    for name in users:
        message(name, 'Hi {}'.format(name), the_message.format(vote_link))
    print('All users succesfully messaged.')
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I've found the answer in another Stack Overflow thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461440/5588987

CR = \r LF = \n

And HTML forms take a line-break as CRLF, so therefore :

\r\n worked !